# Script to Change JAVA_HOME System Variable in Windows

Tags: java, scripting, path, system-variable

I do most of my work against JDK 1.5 - but occasionally I have to change to 1.6. it is a bit painful to have to manually go and change my 'JAVA_HOME' system variable whenever I need to work on a project specific to one or the other (and no, Eclipse doesn't play well in these scenarios - trust me...I've tried.)

I'm looking for a registry script or windows shell script or for that matter any means by which I can "toggle" this system variable with something that is easy to run.

I've messed with the 'set' command, but that only sets the variable for that particular command instance - not globally.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT #1: 
Points of advise:

- Use the **JAVA_HOME** variable in your path variable as well, that way you only have to change the **JAVA_HOME** (which is used in many projects anyways [maven, ant, etc])
- Write the command into a couple batch scripts for easy use
- When you make the change the windows command session will not reflect it right away. You must close and reopen it.

Comment: 3-d: You can use both "set" & "setx" in Your script, thus setting same environment variable for active user session & globally at the same time.

Comment: @barti - thanks for your help, for my scenario setx works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use **`setx`** for that purpose

Like so:

```
setx /M JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17"
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that command - do you have a semi-complete solution? (+1)

Comment: `setx JAVA_HOME "c:\path"` (HKCU) or `setx JAVA_HOME "c:\path" -m` (HKLM)

Comment: Cool, it was that '/M' that I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to add that as I put this in a couple of .bat files, I had to run them as administrator in order to make them work. Thanks it worked great!

Comment: Run `cmd` with administrative permissions. Also reopen applications that use `%JAVA_HOME%` or restart a computer to take effect.