# Android Studio Error "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I downloaded the newest Android Studio, and I wanted to run the Android Jetpack Compose Project, but when I ran it, I got the error:

```
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
You can try some of the following options:
- changing the IDE settings.
- changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
- changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

I already downloaded Java 11 and added Java 11 in *gradle.properties*.

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.10.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The JAVA_HOME shows Java 11, but when I run, it doesn't work -
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.10.jdk/Contents/Home`

How should I do?

My Android Studio version

[image]

My Java version

```
java 11.0.10 2021-01-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode)
```

My *gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.2-bin.zip
```

*build.gradle* classpath

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha13"
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31"
```

File *build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testandroid3"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.31'
    }
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
}
```

Comment: just run npx @react-native-community/cli doctor then it will give you report. press e to install then it will do it everything for you

Answer (score 1437, accepted):

Make sure that your Gradle is using the proper JDK.
Try running `./gradlew --version` in your project's directory. The output should be something like this:

```
Gradle 7.0-rc-2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-04-01 21:26:39 UTC
Revision:     912a3368b654b71250dfc925a20d620393

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.10 (Ubuntu 11.0.10+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.10)
OS:           Linux 5.11.4-051104-generic amd64
```

If the JVM points to version 1.8 then you should change it in settings. You can find it in *Preferences* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Build Tools* → *Gradle* → *Gradle JDK.

[image]

Comment: I have already set it up like this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I had exact same error and changing the JDK in settings fixed it for me, sorry it's not the case for you. The only difference might be the Gradle as I'm using 7.0 rc2, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @VenShine you could also try switching to system gradle instead of the one from project wrapper. Here's some instructions on the example setup using sdkman https://blog.jkl.gg/android-studio-slow-as-fxxx/

Comment: you can confirm that Gradle is using the correct version by calling `./gradlew --version` in your project directory. It'll output the JVM version

Comment: Thanks, I reboot Android Studio, clear cache, then it works.

Comment: m1 still fails to build :(

Comment: I cant even find Build Tools in the path you are showing!

Comment: It is strange that the settings in `Build Tools => Gradle` have been set to 11 but when I do  `flutter doctor -v` it shows `1.8`

Comment: **Changing Gradle JDK to 11, Clean Project, Rebuild Project** worked for me! Please also check whether your *jvmTarget*, *sourceCompatibility* and *targetCompatibility* is set to java 11  ```compileOptions {         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11     }     kotlinOptions {         jvmTarget = '11'     }```

Comment: where to put this sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility

Comment: @Zenko This is because changing settings in Gradle section changes version only for current project, while your `JAVA_HOME` in OS is still an 1.8.

Comment: @ismailshah You need to put it into `build.gradle` file of your project. But, I believe it won't help. Make sure that your system (OS) has Java 11, since just changing Gradle settings didn't help me. 
On MacOS I used `sdkman` to install and use jdk 11. After installing I saw in `./gradlew -verion` proper value for user Java and project started building fine again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The last part of your answer did the trick for me, i wasn't aware of that.

Comment: I put myself into a world of hate by trying to download a JDK (via Android Studio). Make sure to stay away from JDK17. At least for now. I'd download either 11 or 16 - which gradle supports.

Comment: Really useful. I also had to clear `JAVA_HOME` directories I had specified in these locations: `.bash_profile`, `.profile` and `.bashrc` files (Ubuntu 18.04). Now Java 11 is working fine for me, either in Gradle and the Terminal

Comment: I also cannot see the `Build Tools` in the path shown here

Comment: if this setting (Preferences → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle → *Gradle JDK.) doesn't work.
Try to choose in this dropdown "Download JDK..." and choose Amazon version.
It helps me.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 4 on MacOS.  I had to do the Project Structure... section of this answer, and I already had Java 14 so I added Java 14 (Previously only had Java 1.8).  Then I did what Pavel Shorokhov wrote and set org.gradle.java.home to the Java 14 location

Comment: In my case, ./gradelw --version shows the JVM is 15.0.1, but Preferences → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle → *Gradle JDK shows 1.8. So they are seems irrelevant.  And I changed it to 11 and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Worked only after updated system (OS) java to 11

Comment: This solution is not permanent, for each new project we have to do it again, it must a permanent solution.

Comment: Gradle JVM selection process: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle-jvm-selection.html#new_project_jdk

Comment: You can set gradlew JDK in gradle.properties with property: org.gradle.java.home=<JDK dir>

Comment: i tried all the things but still getting this  "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8" error in cmd. any one can help me to solve this problem

Comment: This saved me! I had non specific configuration for debug so I didn't know which store was used :-)

Comment: In my case, changing java version in gradle didn't work.  I didn't have java 11 in my windows.  i installed jdk 11 and insert jdk path to windows config path and it works

Comment: works for me @sampath answer is also working

Comment: sdk use java 11
fixed it, despite having Java 11 everywhere in Android Studio

Comment: had to `cd android` and `gradlew --version` in windows

Comment: Even after setting this, I'd to restart the laptop because gradlew --version was still returning old cache version 1.8. So please restart if setting correct version still doesn't work

Answer (score 298):

For Android Studio Arctic Fox (4.2), with 2020.3.1 Patch 2 on Windows 10 Pro PC:

Step 1

[image]

Step 2

[image]

Comment: this is the solution for the lastest android studio artic fox

Comment: The current Mac version doesn't have that "Android" level or the wrench icon. You can find the Gradle JDK in Preferences under "Build, Execution, Deployment".

Comment: @Oscar This solution worked for me on the latest version on macOS. The `android` level is just from `react-native`, which sets up its project structure like that because it has `android`, `ios`, and more.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Thanks, but the point is that there is no such "wrench" icon in the UI. After I hunted down the appropriate setting under Preferences, the problem was indeed solved.

Comment: Strange. I see the wrench in my Android Studio and I'm running: _"Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 26, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.6
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: IdeaVIM, org.jetbrains.kotlin"_

Comment: @Sampath compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
        useIR = true
    }   >>>>>>>> is it necessary to add in gradle file when we migrate to java 11 ??

Comment: @GyanSwaroopAwasthi Sorry, I'm not a Java/Kotlin developer. i.e. I use Ionic I just install `jdk-16.0.2` and after that did the above configuration.

Comment: This worked :-)

Comment: How on Earth did JetBrains expect me to find that :-)

Comment: Changed it like you mentioned. But when I run ./gradlew --version it still shows JVM 1.8

Comment: This won't solve the problem permanently, but for the actual project, creating a new project would produce same error.

Comment: my android studio does not have this gradle option in build tools.

Answer (score 167):

If you are using Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1) on Windows 10.

This is how you fix the Build failed error:

> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using
> Java 1.8

[image: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8]

1. Open the **Project Structure...**

   *(from the Toolbar)*
   [image: Project Structure on the Toolbar]

   *(or from the File Menu)*
   [image: Project Structure... on the File Menu]
2. Click on the **Gradle Settings** link

   [image: Gradle Settings Link]
3. Select the correct Java JDK from the **Gradle JDK** drop-down list

   [image]

NOTE: If you cannot find the correct [Java JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows), then you'll first need to [download](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows) and install it...

Comment: also fix on mac :)

Comment: This also works on Linux, and...you saved my day!

Comment: I set mine to "Embedded JDK" and that worked.

Comment: In Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1, the setting for the Gradle JDK is moved to Android Studio -> Settings/Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle.

Answer (score 51):

**Android Studio Arctic Fox (4.2) with 2020.3.1 Patch 3 - Mac**

You just need to choose the embedded JDK version 11.0.10 from the Gradle settings of preferences.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the 'Gradle JDK' option

Comment: Open android module and see if its a flutter project. You will see this Gradle JDK option only from android module. @LukePighetti

Answer (score 41):

This is how I fixed it on macOS.

```
./gradlew --version
```

[image]

Go to *Preference* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Gradle*

[image]

Change the Gradle JDK to your latest version.

[image]

I have only one JDK (Microsoft build [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) 17) installed before installing Android Studio. For unknown reasons, a JDK 1.8 has been installed along Android Studio and set as the Gradle default at `/Users/<username>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_322`

Comment: Thanks for this. Selecting `Embedded JDK version 11.0.11` worked for me on my M1 mac.

Comment: `Go to Preference -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle`

Comment: This is not working for me do you have any thing else to solve this problem. @MaserWil

Comment: @vainu that's all I did to solve the problem. Sorry if this can't help.

Comment: I don't see the 'Gradle JDK' option

Comment: I select Embedded Java and it works for me.

Comment: You're the man. I had moved from Spring, using Java 21 to a flutter project, requiring 11.

Answer (score 40):

On [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) I solved it by the following steps.

1. Opened file *~/.zshrc* in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)
2. Added this line:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"
   ```
3. Saved the file
4. Reloaded the terminal with modified file by running

   ```
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```
5. testing if the changes have been loaded by running

   ```
   echo $JAVA_HOME
   ```
6. Verified that the correct location is displaying.
7. Verified that the Gradle is displaying correct Java 11 version by running

   ```
   cd android
   ./gradlew --version
   ```

And here is the result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-12-22 12:37:54 UTC
Revision:     6f556c80f945dc54b50e0be633da6c62dbe8dc71

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.12 (JetBrains s.r.o. 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.2.1 aarch64
```

Tried to build it again by running:

```
yarn android
```

And it's succeeded.

Comment: I would like to know for Windows OS. :O

Comment: In Android Studio Electric Eel version, it should be `export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home"`. Simply change `jre` with `jbr`.

Comment: I LOVE YOUUU THANKSS!!! It also works on non Mac M1

Answer (score 39):

In Android Studio I just did this:

*Preferences* → *Build,Execution,Deployment* → *Build Tools* → *Gradle*

Easy peasy.

[image: Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools-> Gradle]

Comment: IntelliJ is so frustrating. So it did this with every project. Now I'm at one of my WearOS projects, got this complaint, changed it to the Studio's Java (1.17 I think). Now I'm getting `Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found.`.

Answer (score 34):

I got this error when I started `gradlew ktlintFormat` in the Terminal of [Arctic Fox build](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview).

1. I opened *Project Structure* (menu *File* → *Project Structure*) and selected Java 11, but it didn't help even after a restart of Android Studio.

   [image]
2. Then I changed the Java path in *Settings* (see the accepted answer), but it didn't help. You should set it.
3. I tried to change Windows system variables and changed `JAVA_HOME`.

   ([A short way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338410/script-to-change-java-home-system-variable-in-windows): run `cmd` with administrative rights and write: `setx /M JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11"`, and then restart Android Studio)

   Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, press "System", and enter "va".

   [image]

   [image]

   I pressed <kbd>Edit</kbd> button and "Browse Directory...", and then selected JRE (or JDK) folder (without `bin`) of Java 11. Then <kbd>OK</kbd>, and <kbd>OK</kbd> (as always).

   [image]
4. I opened `cmd` (command line in Windows) and typed: `%JAVA_HOME%`. It wrote me this error:

   > 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   > operable program or batch file.

   Looking at *[Setting the JAVA_HOME Variable in Windows](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)*, I found that we should replace `Program Files` with `Progra~1` (yes, this [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) trick still works). So, replace JAVA_HOME again like in the picture below (C:\Progra~1\Android\Androi~1\jre).

   [image]
5. Restart Android Studio or reset the computer.

Comment: I had same problem on MacOS. Set Gradle JDK to version 11 and the build now works.

Comment: compileOptions { sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 } kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "11" useIR = true } >>>>>>>> is it necessary to add in gradle file when we migrate to java 11 ??

Comment: @GyanSwaroopAwasthi, thanks for a notice. In one project we use `JavaVersion.VERSION_11` and `jvmTarget` (JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()), as you wrote. I think, after this changes Android Studio will ask to upgrade to Java 11.

Comment: that really help me, thank you! Finally I just downloaded last java machine and install it. After laptop reboot version changed!

Answer (score 30):

I downloaded the 11 JDK again and it works. This saves you time as you don’t have to clear the cache, build, and rebuild your project.

[image: Downloading new JDK (pick version 11 again or a later version)]

Comment: My solution still works as of today, you can choose the latest version like Amazon Corretto 20...

Answer (score 29):

You can solve it in this simple way.

1. Go to *https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html*
2. Download the JDK ZIP file of your system. (Let’s say Windows)
3. Extract it in any folder with high permissions under your PC main directory
4. Now open and Go to your Android studio project structure located at men File* → *Project structure*.
5. And paste the directory where you unzipped the JDK version here. As you see, mine is JDK 16 as at now and installed in that directory as seen in the picture:

   [image]

Comment: compileOptions { sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 } kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "11" useIR = true } >>>>>>>> is it necessary to add in gradle file when we migrate to java 11 ??

Answer (score 24):

When I upgraded to [Android Studio 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (Dolphin) I got this error, and it is *sooooo* easy to fix. This answer is the easiest, fastest and the best...

In Android Studio I just did this:

*Preferences* → *Build,Execution,Deployment* → *Build Tools* → *Gradle. Select Java 11 or 12, etc..

Easy peasy

See the picture.

[image]

Comment: The second answer (with self-plagiarism). [The first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur/74163825#74163825).

Answer (score 20):

I got this error when I updated one of the dependencies in Android Studio that requires Java 11. You just need to follow these steps.

1. Download the Java 11. For Mac, download a .dmg file and for Windows a ZIP file. Link: [Download Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/ae/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html)
2. Select options at Android studio

   [image]

   Follow the steps and choose your newly saved Java SDK

   [image]

   Follow the steps and choose your newly saved Java SDK.

   [image]

   (Follow the steps and choose your newly saved Java SDK.)

Answer (score 17):

You can do it this way (menu *File* → *Build* option):

[image: Menu File -> Build option]

Answer (score 16):

If you are using **MS App Center**, you may face the same kind of issue when you use Java 11 in your Android project. If you are looking a solution for MS App Center issue. This may help you!

- Go to `https://appcenter.ms/users/user1/apps/yourapp/build/branches`
- Click settings icon to go to `Build configuration`
- Scroll down to `Environment` and turn on.
- Set `JAVA_HOME` to `$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)`

[image]

Comment: that worked form, man you are a lifesaver xD, THANK YOU

Answer (score 11):

On Mac, only **setting JAVA_HOME to JDK 11** embedded to Android Studio helped.

I did it with this command in the command line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=ENTER_PATH_TO_JDK_HERE
```

`PATH_TO_JDK` could be something like `/Users/userName/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/203.7583922/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home`

Comment: Just updating Java to 11 on my Mac actually helped. Gradle seems to use the system Java version when called from the terminal (even in the terminal within Android Studio).

Answer (score 11):

#### For a [Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(software)) project with Visual Studio Code

Add this to file *gradle.properties*:

```
org.gradle.java.home=<path to JDK 11>
```

Example:

```
C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.15
```

[image: gradle.properties]

Comment: I think this would probably be better suited for `local.properties` if you care about best practices.

Comment: Works great in my case!

Answer (score 10):

I was just having the same problem -

> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run

Resolve it by replacing the value of *Gradle JDK*, *"JDK 1.9"* by *"Android Studio SDk default JD 11.0.11"* in menu *Settings* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Build Tools* → *Gradle*.

Answer (score 10):

#### For macOS users

The bundled JDK into macOS is 1.8, but now we need 11. Make Gradle use AndroidStudio's JDK for building the project:

Into file `<PROJECT_ROOT>/gradle.properties`, add line:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Users/.../Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/.../Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
```

---

Note: If you're **not use Jetbrains Toolbox** and you've installed Android Studio into `/Application`, use this path instead (thanks to @AndrewBekhtold):

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the JVM built into Android Studio?org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home

Comment: Mac user here. The line above by @AndrewBekhtold worked for me

Comment: @AndrewBekhtold added to answer your suggestion. Your solution is correct, but only for users who doesn't use Jetbrains Toolbox. Toolbox's users have installed Studio into another folder, not in /Application.

Comment: For Mac Silicon you may want to use `org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home`

Comment: mac user here. I using visual studio code and android studio code. For the problem encounter with my existed react native project. The line above by @AndrewBekhtold worked for me. thank you so much !!

Answer (score 10):

**⚠️ Note:** this is a solution if you are getting this error on the `GitHub Actions Pipeline`

If you are using [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11) in your project, but the GitHub Action Pipeline that builds the application is set to use Java 1.8, you will get this error.

To fix it, replace the following:

```
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
```

with:

```
      - name: set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'zulu'
          java-version: 11
```

Comment: Where to add this in project?

Comment: If you are getting this on the Github Actions Pipeline, you could change the Step in the Action *.yml* File that is under the `.github/workflows` folder on your Project.

Comment: Although this does not answer the OP question, it is related to the topic and is helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

All the solutions here are helpful for Java 11. But if you don't want to upgrade to Java 11 then you should just downgrade Android Gradle plugin (ADP) to 4.X as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I have concluded that Gradle calls the version of Java installed on the system, regardless of Android Studio settings.

On macOS, check the list of installed Java versions in the system with the command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

If there is no Java 11 or higher among them, you will get an error like the author of the question.

The solution is to install the Java 11 or higher.

The second solution is to make a symlink in the folder `~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` to the JRE embedded in Android Studio with the command:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre" "~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/Android Studio Default JRE"
```

Additionally you can add this line to `~/.zshenv`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
```

You can get installation paths for different Java versions if needed:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11
```

or

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
```

Comment: Other above answers have you check the java version in Android Studio. This shows I already have java 11 installed. Following your steps to check using `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` is what helped me.

Comment: Thanks. None of the above worked

Answer (score 9):

If you are currently using Android Studio [Arctic Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (4.2):

- You can set manually the Gradle JDK (menu *Preferences* → *Build Tools* → *Gradle* → *Gradle JDK* (use or download JDK 11))
- Restore the default setting and don't do the previous tip in all projects (menu *File* → *Manage IDE settings* → *Restore Default Settings*)

Comment: compileOptions { sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 } kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "11" useIR = true } >>>>>>>> is it necessary to add in gradle file when we migrate to java 11 ??

Answer (score 9):

- For the latest version, this works for my Windows machine
- Menu *File* → *Project Structure*

  [image: Project]
- Choose the JDK 11 from you machine that you installed
- Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>.
- Restart your Android Studio after these changes
- Now, you're good to go

[image]

Comment: nothing worked for me . i just updated flutter 3.0 and jdk11.0.5

Comment: finally worked for me android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 11
        targetCompatibility 11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
        useIR = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

Comment: This is nearly unreadable. Can you make the window smaller before taking the screenshot and crop the image to leave out irrelevant parts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by adding this to the gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

But your Java 11 may be located in a different directory.

Example path for Windows:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-13.0.2
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to run the [benchmarking samples](https://github.com/android/performance-samples) for the first time.

The instructions to run the sample were to execute

`./gradlew macrobenchmark:cC`

in the IDE terminal, but in my case this resulted with the same error.

I had tried the accepted answer above from M Tomczyński above, but that didn't work for me. I believe this was as a result of my existing config for `JAVA_HOME` (which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65562670/2199001)).

This also meant that option 2, changing my `JAVA_HOME` config, wasn't an option.

The change which did work for me though was option 3 in the suggestions above. I checked the path for Java 11 from the answer above and added that into `gradle.properties`, and then sync'd gradle as per the IDE prompt, and re-ran the macrobenchamark gradle command successfully.

`org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 5):

Changing the Gradle JDK to 11 worked for me in Android Studio [Arctic Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (4.2):

Step 1:

Navigate to: menu *File* → *Setting* → *Build, Execution, Deployment* → *Build Tools* → *Gradle*

Step 2:

Change Gradle JDK to 11, below the Gradle Projects.

Step 3:

*Apply*, and *Rebuild Project*!

Comment: compileOptions { sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11 } kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "11" useIR = true } >>>>>>>> is it necessary to add in gradle file when we migrate to java 11 ??

Comment: I didn't find Gradle JDK option on this path ?

Answer (score 5):

#### Add the Java Home path to wrapper.properties

Changing the Gradle JDK in Android Studio Preferences didn't work for me.

But I was able to correct the JDK by adding the `org.gradle.java.home` path in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

# I had to add this line (macOS)
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
```

I found the JAVA_HOME path by going to menu *File* → *Project Structure* → *SDKs* → Choose the JDK you want to use → *JDK home path*.

[image]

After that, I was able again to run [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:using_wrapper) ([`gradlew`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700798/gradlew-command-not-found)) commands.

Comment: I had tried everything including resetting my IDE settings, changing JAVA_HOME, etc.
This finally did worked.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use JDK 11 and still want to use JDK 1.8, you can revert back the Android plugins as below.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '4.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '4.2.0' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you run into this problem from the terminal in Android Studio, you should configure JAVA_HOME in your environment into Java 11, set the [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) JDK in Preferences can't solve. I guess that running Gradle from the terminal and running Gradle from the IDE are not the same process and they use different JDK location.

Answer (score 3):

None of the previous answers worked for me in [Android Studio 4.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (Arctic Fox), 2020.3.1 Patch 3.

Only adding `org.gradle.java.home=<Path-to-JDK-v11>` to `gradle.properties` worked in my case.

If you are using Linux, just add `org.gradle.java.home=/opt/android-studio/jre`.

Comment: Worked for me when nothing else suggested here did, Win10, AS 4.1.1

Answer (score 3):

### My environment

- Windows 10
- Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
- Flutter 3.3.9

### How I solved this issue...

If setting the **Java** version in the **Gradle** properties and in the **Environment Variables** seems not to have any effect, chances are that there is a *Global setting* from **Gradle** blocking *yours*.

Go to

```
C:\Users\<yourUserName>\.gradle
```

and look for a file named `gradle.properties`. If

```
org.gradle.java.home
```

is set there, then its value will override any setting you use in the project.

So, the solution would be either remove that line, or set right there the **java** version you wish. In my case I got it working be editing the file as to look like:

```
#org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was using Android Studio version before [Arctic Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio#Version_history) (4.2). And it seems that only Arctic Fox supports JDK 11.

Answer (score 2):

**In Windows** I got this error when upgrading [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native) v0.67 to 0.68 from CMD of the directory without installing update [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) 11.

First I install:

```
choco source add -n chocolatey -s 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
```

Then I run this:

```
choco install -y nodejs-lts openjdk11 // Without nodejs-lts I have already installed Node.js
```

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a [Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(software)) application and it was not running on my phone stating that Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11.

My Android Studio version was very old. I was not seeing any of the options shown in the screenshots. I updated Android Studio after setting the JAVA_HOME in system environment variables. And it automatically picked Java 11.

Answer (score 2):

If you just modify the JDK version from 1.8 to 11 in Preferences → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle, you may still get that error.

By running the command `./gradlew --version`, you can see the JDK version is still 1.8. So, we need to change the `JAVA_HOME` value in `~/.bash_profile` to your real JDK-11 location. Here is the diff after modifying:

```
- export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
+ export JAVA_HOME=/Users/xx/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.14.1/Contents/Home
```

Then, reopen your Android Studio, and everything will work well.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the below property in file *gradle.properties*.

org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home

(This is for macOS. Give the path as per OS). This fix will work for any [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) version.

Answer (score 2):

My environment:

- Android Studio 4.1.1
- Java 1.8

You need not to switch Java 11 or higher. You can follow my steps as below.

**Solved by:**

Changing gradle classpath at android/build.gradle file under dependencies,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

TO

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For macbook m chips

first check JVM check for this case it is 1.8.0_39
[image]

then go to project structure (file>project structure) on sdk section select add sdk then click download JDK With a version matching with JVM for 1.8 download version 18 etc
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I saw this because on my [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) server with pipeline set up, I needed to build from the [docker-android-sdk/android-28](https://github.com/docker-android-sdk/android-28/blob/master/Dockerfile) image which is packaged with openjdk-8.

I added the following line to my *bitbucket-pipelines.yml* file to install openjdk-11 before running the Gradle build:

```
- apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is a solution if you are getting this error on the [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops).

If you are using Java 11 in your project, but the Azure DevOps pipeline that builds the application is set to use Java 1.8, you will get this error.

To fix it, add following (for Windows pool):

```
    - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '11'
        jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
        jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
```

Comment: What is *"Window pool"*? Do you mean *"Windows pool"*? (as in [the operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows))

Answer (score 0):

For me it’s as simple as making sure I'm using the Gradle JDK located in *[Android Studio installation path]/jre*.

Try it. It might also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. Deleting the folder for JDK 1.8 in my user folder.
2. Restarted Android Studio.
3. Android Studio dropped down a bar at the top of the screen asking if I wanted to change which JDK to use or redownload 1.8.
4. I selected JDK 16 and all worked!

Comment: (The current latest version of the JDK is 17.0.1.)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't know how to change the JDK version, if you are on *Mac*, use this command in terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/*
```

This will remove all JDKs from the system. Then, just download the required JDK version and you are all *up*!

Comment: god damn you man.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on MacOS was first, find where Java Home is:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'
```

then update my JAVA_HOME export in `~/.bash_profile` to reflect the output of that command:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.1_1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows (maybe will work on other systems too):

- Get latest Java version: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk20-windows
- Install it
- update JAVA_HOME Variable (Windows 10 – Search for Environment Variables then select Edit the system environment variables) with the folder path, where you installed it
- reboot your PC
- check your java version by command: java --version

Answer (score 0):

Using `Flutter` with `Android Studio`, I had the message:

> Android Studio Error "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run.
> You are currently using Java 1.8"

I tried to define in "Project Structure" Java 11 as the version used for my project with no success.

[image]

But setting the path of Java 11 into my `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Users\\jorgesys\\.jdks\\corretto-11.0.20
```

my application was created with no problems