# App center Error: /Users/runner/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return code: 1

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using react native to build my apps and thought to give Microsoft app center a chance.

The main issue I have is that I cannot finish the build.

This should be a non-production build that will be tested by the QA team.

This is the error I get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70680838/8445696

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue.

I was the Gradle version, there is no 7.3**

The latest version is 7.1.1 so when I changed the URL to gradle-7.1.1-all.zip It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a java compatibility issue with your project gradle!

Open your app center build config page > enable the Environment variables

Set JAVA_HOME as $(JAVA_HOME_11_X64) and click on save and build.

[image]