# Error: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. -& Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have tried all the possible solutions for this error. Require guidance here:

I am using Windows Laptop : Android Studio 2020.3.1.22

Below is the build.graddle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication3"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5")
}
```

also my graddle wrapper properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

my output of ./gradlew --version

```
Gradle 7.0.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-05-14 12:02:31 UTC
Revision:     1ef1b260d39daacbf9357f9d8594a8a743e2152e

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_275 (Azul Systems, Inc. 25.275-b01)
```

Android Sdk version: C:\Users\User name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Gradle JDK: 11 version 11.0.12 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12

Java Version:

```
C:\Users\Vainav Shah\StudioProjects\MyApplication3>java --version
java 16.0.2 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Please guide to resolve this error:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-currently-using-java-1-8

Comment: Have you tried setting it from within Android Studio? Settings -> Build,Execution & Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle.

And change the Gradle JDK to  a JDK 11 installation.

Comment: yes done! Gradle JDK: 11 version 11.0.12 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12  Still the same issue

Comment: Did you try to Invalidate cache and restart android studio?

Comment: Yes! 2-3 times No effect :(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well I also face same issue

[image: Image showing same error]

What worked for me is this (In Windows 10 OS based Laptop)

Go to File-->Settings-->Build,Execution,Deployment-->Build Tools-->Gradle

Now here -->Gradle JDK change 1.8 to 11(given in dropdown).

See image given to get more clear idea.

[image: Steps to get Answer to given problem]

After that just REBUILD YOU PROJECT. It worked for me. (see attached image).
[image: Screen showing every thing is fine now and answer worked properlly.]

SO ERROR IS SOLVED AND EVERY THING IS FINE IN PROJECT NOW.

HOPE THIS WORKS FOR YOU TOO! THANKS.

Comment: problem solved!

Comment: I tried this many times but this is not working for me can you suggest any other things to help this am getting this error "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8." in cmd can you help me to solve this @SaiAbhijit

Comment: Also You can see Video here https://youtu.be/9mmY8rLvoRU

Answer (score 2):

For Windows -> File-> Settings-> Build,Execution,Deployment-> Build Tools-> Gradle-> Gradle JDK and select java 11

Answer (score 2):

This error happened to me while I was using Jetpack Compose and it required java 11, but I was using java 1.8. So if you cannot find jdk 11 in dropdown that means you have not downloaded it yet, so click download jdk and download 11 and click apply).

Answer (score 2):

## Add the JavaHome path to wrapper.properties

Changing the Gralde JDK from Android Studio Preferences didn't work for me.

But I was able to correct the JDK by adding the `org.gradle.java.home` path in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

# I had to add this line (macos)
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home
```

I found the JAVA_HOME path by going to `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `SDKs` -> Choose the JDK you want to use -> `JDK home path`.

[image]

After that, I was able again to run gradlew commands.

Comment: This fixed my problem. I use flutter and Mac

Answer (score 1):

Just change jvmTarget to 11, like bellow code.

```
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8' 
    }
```

change '1.8' to '11'

```
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
```