# "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run" While publishing jitpack library

Tags: java, android, gradle, jitpack

I'm trying to publish an empty jitpack library for test purposes by using [this](https://github.com/emreakcan/android-lib-jitpack-test) github repo

But I'm having

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

Full error : https://jitpack.io/com/github/emreakcan/android-lib-jitpack-test/2.0.0/build.log

My IDE settings are set to version 11,
Java 1.8 is not even installed on my mac.

```
emre@Emres-MacBook-Pro / % java -version
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10-adhoc.admin.jdk11u)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10-adhoc.admin.jdk11u, mixed mode)
emre@Emres-MacBook-Pro / %
```

If I add

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openlogic-openjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I'm having the following error

```
* What went wrong:
Value '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openlogic-openjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)
```

My gradle is also set to 11

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '11'
}
```

I tried those links
[Error: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. -& Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728918/error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-currently-using-ja)

[Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-currently-using-java-1-8)

Project works on my local, I'm having those errors on jitpack website once when I push my tags

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved by using a `jitpack.yml` (added it into project root), turns out jitpack using 1.8 as default and doesn't care about what you set on gradle.

```
# configuration file for building snapshots and releases with jitpack.io
jdk:
  - openjdk11
before_install:
  - ./scripts/prepareJitpackEnvironment.sh
```

Details
https://jitpack.io/docs/BUILDING/#java-version