# Android Studio - 'com.android.internal.application' Java 11 - fix gradle projects not visibile in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the issue

Error: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. -& Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'

[Error: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. -& Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728918/error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-currently-using-ja)

The solution requires to download JDK 11.0, then change gradle projects - the option is not available in Android studio. Do I need to upgrade android studion or change the setups?

[image]

Comment: May be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68616770/15005298

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to do anything that complex. First, download OpenJDK 11 from [here](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/9/GPL/openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin.zip). Extract the contents of the zip in a folder. Then, find the `gradle.properties` file in your android project (Create one if it's not there). Then. add this property to it:

```
org.gradle.java.home=path/to/jdk11
```

Note: Do not point towards the bin folder, just point towards the home JDK 11 directory.