# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

I get the same issue as in this question when I do react-native run-android. I think it wants java 11 but I want to continue with 1.8. How can I do it?

[Android Studio - 'com.android.internal.application' Java 11 - fix gradle projects not visibile in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69997158/android-studio-com-android-internal-application-java-11-fix-gradle-project)

Comment: It clearly says that you can't use java 1.8 . To continue with JDK 11 , go to Project Structure > SDK location > Jdk location was moved to Gradle Settings > Gradle JDK drop down menu > Select "Embedded JDK".

Comment: when i change it as said ," Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version." this error not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do;

1. log into my computer
2. right click and select properties
3. enter advanced system settings
4. add new path name: JAVA_HOME
5. select the java 11 jdk location and save it

or

1. open cmd for adminstator
2. setx JAVA_HOME -m "path"

After doing all of them, delete your old React Native project and install a new one.

or

1. open project with android stiduo
2. find node_moduls -> react-native-gradle-plugin -> build.gradle -> change java 1.8 to java 11.0

Comment: Modifying files in node_modules folder is not a good idea.

Comment: you are right but its working

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do：

- Download jdk11:
  https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html
- Config `android/gradle.properties`

```bash
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/contents/Home
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76246028/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

if you need to upgrade jdk, android studio provides a quick way to do it
**File** ->**Setting** ->**Build,Execution,Deployment** ->**Build Tools** ->**Gradle**
In Gradle JDK selected version you want

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands:

`nano ./zshrc`

Find JAVA_HOME and replace with your v11 java path.
You can find the path here:

`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

Save the file, re-launch the terminal and try again.