# How to build Android project?

Tags: android, tfsbuild

I have a well-functioning TFS build settings fro my projects which is works very well with my older android projects.

So recently I creted a new Android project, and I tried to build and create an apk with TFS, but I got an error when It started the unit test section, which says:

Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.

> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:

- changing the IDE settings.
- changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
- changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

In Android studio I checked, it is use the JDK 11, and in local I can build a release version from my project.

Unfortunatelly I don't have enough knowledge in TFS server builds, so I don't know what I have to do.

I can add more information, if it is helps, but please tell me what to attach

Comment: That's not error of your project but the environment that tries to build your project. It basically says there is Java 8 instead of 11 on the build server.

Comment: Thanks, so if I download, and install java 11 it could be solve the problem?

Comment: Your question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/error-message-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-currently)

Comment: I saw that, but in my tfs server there is an old android studi version, and I don't think It builds the projects. I think the projects are build by Visual Studio, but I may be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this.

Although I installed the latest java sdk, and I refreshed the JAVE_HOME environment variable, but I didn't restart the server. When I restarted, the build was successfully

Answer (score 0):

Set Gradle JDK to embedded(11.0.10) and same for environment variable.[image: Go to Files>Settings> and search gradle and set jdk version.]