# How can I change the default JDK for new Android Studio projects?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Every time I create a new project in Android Studio I'm met with the following build error:

```
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
```

I already know how to [change the project settings to use JDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/error-message-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-currently), but I'd like to **fix this problem permanently for all new projects**.

How can I get Android Studio / Gradle to use JDK 11 instead of 1.8 for all new projects?

Comment: I was able to workaround this by removing JDK 1.8 (`mv /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk /tmp/`), then doing `Android Studio-> Invalidate Caches and Restart`, however, I'd be interested to know if there's a solution which doesn't involve such a drastic step.

Comment: did you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to your system variables

Comment: Yes, `JAVA_HOME` is set to the Java 11 SDK installation path.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue

to solve this in Android Studio

go to Menu:

```
File ->
 settings -> 
    build, execution , Development -> 
      build tools -> 
        gradle ->
```

set Gradle JDK to be Android studio default JDK (should be version 11 or select version 11)

[image]

Comment: This does not set the JDK permenantly for all new projects

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, and I eventually found that it was because my JAVA_HOME environment variable was set to an older JDK. I don't use java for anything but android development, so the solution in my case was to simply unset JAVA_HOME. After that, new projects defaulted to the JDK that's bundled with android studio.

How to unset your JAVA_HOME, will depend on how it was set in the first place, but in my case (macos) it was defined in ~/.zshrc — I simply removed the line starting with:

```
$JAVA_HOME=
```

If you need that variable to be defined, then you can try pointing it to a more up-to-date version of the JDK. If that's not possible either, then my guess is that you will have to continue setting the JDK on a per-project basis.