# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8, but i'm using java 11

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I imported a Flutter project, and when I tried to run it, I got this message error:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/omer358/FlutterProjects/MyProjects/ConverterNOW/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I searched for some solutions, one of them suggested that I'm using java1.8 but that was not the case!

```
omer358@OMO:~/FlutterProjects/MyProjects/ConverterNOW/android$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.0.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-05-14 12:02:31 UTC
Revision:     1ef1b260d39daacbf9357f9d8594a8a743e2152e

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.14 (Ubuntu 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.22.10)
OS:           Linux 5.13.0-35-generic amd64
```

can you help me make go away!

Comment: Have you checked you Android Studio settings?

Comment: I"m using vs code

Comment: You may have then 2 java version installed and the jre maybe pointed to the version 1.8

Comment: I considered that too, I removed java completely from my machine and installed java 11 again, I also set the JAVA_HOME to /usr/bin/java

Comment: I solved this problem by delete my source flutter SDK, download the newest flutter SDK, this problem occurs when I changed the version of flutter from v3 to v1 by git. Maybe the sdk file crashed for my situation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your place set up?

Is the gradle java version too low

```
   JAVA_HOME D:\Android\Android Studio\jre
   %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

I had that problem and I had solved it doing this:

Add the command below in gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.1.1.
```

In my case:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.1.1
```

Then, in terminal, change the directory to android. (I use windows)

```
cd android
```

Finally, i wrote `./gradlew signingreport` in terminal and i got SHA1 and SHA-256.

Comment: org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.1.1.

Comment: How do I get the java path on macos?

Comment: @genericUser I tried `which java` and that gave me the path but it still didn't work

Comment: @genericUser I used the default path where all my jdk are installed. /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Answer (score 21):

in my mac, there is no gradle projects settings, so this is what i solved my problem:

## 1. Open project structure in android studio:

[image]

## 2. Follow platform settings > android studio default JDK:

[image]

## 3. Then download JDK with this settings:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm for mac!

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions worked for me I use Vs Code btw so the thing I did was first go to android->build gradle and look for this line of code

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**AND CHANGE THAT TO**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

changed the version.This will work for sure if the above methods didnt

Answer (score 3):

in vs code in ur explorer open  android>app>gradle.properties  and then add this code

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.2
```

if u use another version of jdk then replace jdk-18.0.2 to jdk-ur version
the all code in gradle.properties should be like this

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.2
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and eventually solved it. Here are the steps I followed.

1. Copy the path that you installed java 11 (or higher in my case I have java 12).

In my case, the path was, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1`.

2. Go to the flutter project --> android --> gradle.properties
3. Add the path as follows,

`org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12.0.1`

After adding the path your `gradle.properties` file should look like as follows,

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12.0.1
```

4. Then save and re-run the flutter app.

Note that you should add extra forward slashes as above in my given code snippet when adding a path.

Answer (score 2):

**The headache-less solution:**

Just uninstall your (older) version of android studio, go to their website, and install the latest version. This should automatically update your java version to whatever your Flutter project requires.

Worked for me after trying lots of other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem but what I did is that I deleted the android folder and run it again. If your are using android studio, in your terminal past this **Flutter create .** and it will build the android project using your specified SDK instead

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who tried java -version and still failed even though you have the correct version or higher, go to folder android > gradle.properties and add this: org.gradle.java.home={your jdk directory}, I attached mine as example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ32E.png

Answer (score 1):

In my case , running flutter app with VS code in mac M1, had similiar issue

I have added the below line in gradle.properties

org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home

Note:
Initially I added the value in ''. ie
org.gradle.java.home='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home'

then it gave error. later I removed ''

Answer (score 1):

I found myself with the exact same problem, I searched a lot how to make the sdk changes, tried many of the solutions that are mentioned in several POSTs and nothing seemed to work or solve the problem, however the one that did work provisionally was to overwrite the version from gradle.properties with

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64
```

But it turns out that the problem was with Android Studio, previous versions by default handle JRE 1.8 and to have it functional with v11, you just have to update android studio to its most recent version, I installed Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

Here I leave the screenshots to identify the case.

Console problem running a Flutter project

[image]
[image]

Result of the flutter doctor before

[image]

Result of flutter doctor after updating android studio to its latest version

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using

```
    - Flutter 3.3.2
    - Android Studio 4.1.1
    - Java 1.8
```

**Solution:**

*changing gradle classpath at android/build.gradle file under dependencies*

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

TO

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem after installing gradle separately from android studio so ***ionic cap open android*** worked fine but ***ionic cap run android*** had this problem.

so with ***brew info java11*** I could see the suggestion to symlink the openjdk@11 but it didn't work for capacitor.

Then I edited the ***android/gradle/gradle.properties*** file and added:

org.gradle.java.home=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17

And that cured the problem for me on my mac

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me that I removed [project_name].iml file in the project folder, and ran the main.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help users that are using **Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1** :

In my case i had already installed java 8 from oracle and gradle seems to use it even if i set the Android studio embedded JDK as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002271/18145895) say

However it didn't solve the issue.

So i uninstall the java 8, rebooted.
And now i got the message

> JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH

So why it don't find the JDK even if the JDK is set into android studio ?

I found these issues: [#1](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119325) [#2](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106674) [#3](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110807) that say that flutter searches for default android studio java home in `<Android studio install folder>/jre` (empty) folder; **BUT** the embedded JDK folder is `<Android studio install folder>/jbr`.

This may be the main reason why gradle found java 8 even if i set the embeded JDK from the beginning: that's because it couldn't find it and so gradle fallback to the java installed on the system or set by the JAVA_HOME env variable.

I solved both the issues by using:

- In Unix-like (Linux, MacOs, ...) [source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106674#issuecomment-1381621542) :

```
cd <Android Studio Install folder>
rm -r ./jre
ln -s jbr jre
```

- In Windows CMD (maybe as administrator) [source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106674#issuecomment-1354038250):

```
cd <Android Studio Install folder>
rmdir /s .\jre
mklink /D .\jre .\jbr ( or mklink /J .\jre .\jbr )
```

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ Idea & Mac solution

1. Ensure you have Java 11 or whatever version Flutter requires by checking your directory.  Java versions are usually stored in /Users/yourname/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
2. If you need to download a new one go to:

   IntelliJ Idea -> Project Structure -> SDKs -> + (plus button) -> Download JDK -> select your version, vendor and location
3. Go to `yourflutterapp\android\gradle.properties` and declare the Java version you want to use by adding this line to the end of the file (replace the path with the path specified in step 2)

   org.gradle.java.home=/Users/yourusernamehere/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.19/Contents/Home

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio, then File >> Project Structure , then check NDK location like this  and download required files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the JAVA_HOME environment variable. Had multiple versions in C:\Program Files\Java\ and the environment variable was pointing to an old version.