# Flutter "You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle." error

Tags: java, android, flutter, sdk

When i create a new project, and press run i get this error.

[image]

The fact is i do already have jdk verison of 15 and my previously created projects do open and run without any errors. Also, if i add `org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-15.0.1` line to my `gradle.properties` file the app runs without error but this way just does not seems right way to do it.

I have tried to change the SDK version from the project structure like some other questions and answers but it did not worked either. As an additon to other problems i do not have the same project structure screen as they showed so.

[image]

[image]

I do not know what to do right now, i would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Here I have written the solution, You can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/74599949/6109034

Answer (score 0):

You should delete .gradle folder under user name. Then again run your project.

Comment: shaik h if you are talking about C:\users\myusername  then i did deleted it but did not worked again.

Comment: Then you need to reinstall android studio again.

Comment: After that, go to android studio folder at c:\ ... Delete duplicate android studio folder.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

change  gradle to 4.1.0
and it will be run