# How to Upgrade Flutter Java Version

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing a problem with creating new flutter project
whenever i try to run it it gives me this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\BCC\source\repos\Flutter\flutter_new_demo\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     Your current JDK is located in  C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 50s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle. │
│                                                                               │
│ To get Java 11, update to the latest version of Android Studio on             │
│ https://developer.android.com/studio/install.                                 │
│                                                                               │
│ To check the Java version used by Flutter, run `flutter doctor -v`.           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.abanoub.eg.flutter_new_demo"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**Flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2846], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.7.12 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4d9e56e694 (10 days ago), 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
    • Engine revision 1a65d409c7
    • Dart version 2.19.6
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\BCC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\BCC\.android\avd\Pixel_4_XL_API_30.avd;C:\Users\BCC\.android\avd\Nexus_6_API_30.avd;
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Professional 2019 16.11.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional
    • Visual Studio Professional 2019 version 16.11.31702.278
    X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete. Please reinstall Visual Studio.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Redmi Note 7 (mobile) • 6decdeee • android-arm64  • Android 9 (API 28)
    • Windows (desktop)     • windows  • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2846]
    • Chrome (web)          • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.138
    • Edge (web)            • edge     • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 112.0.1722.58

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

after research I've tried the following

1. updating the java version to 20.0.1

   java version "20.0.1" 2023-04-18
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.1+9-29, mixed mode, sharing)
2. down-grade Gradle version in Android/build.gradle
   from 7.2.0 to  4.1.0

but it did not work for me.

i'm not sure what exactly causes the problem but i think that the java version flutter uses is 1.8
while i already installed version 20.0.1 but i can not get flutter to use this version.
if this is the case how can i do that.
if not what could be the case

Comment: maybe this answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71534536/12037101) is useful