# After changed JAVA.VERSION to 11 I get "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have changed `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to `JavaVersion.VERSION_11` in build. gradle files for all modules. In my PC I have JDK 11, JAVA_HOME and path are ok, in project:

[image]

But I still get
`Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'. Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8. You can try some of the following options: changing the IDE settings. changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable. changing` org.gradle.java.home`in`gradle.properties`

my gradle.properties:
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.gradle.parallel=true android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur

Comment: @Manohar, I have read this topic. I have the sane settings. But still get this error

Comment: Try restarting the system after changing the path variable.

Answer (score 7):

if you're using mac, Check you're java version on android studio. point to android studio menu then preference or `command + ,`

[image]

Update bash profile to java 11 which android Studio has.

```
vim /users/{username}/.bash_profile
```

locate path variable java to android folder folder

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin
```

[image]

dont forget to type

```
source /Users/{username}/.bash_profile
```

finally check our java version, type

```
which java && javac --version
```

or running `./gradlew --version`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check java path in Environment variables and make sure you don't have Java 8 in path and you have java 11 or newer

Comment: yes, all my variables are ok.

Comment: Do you have java home variable in variables

Comment: yes. I have: `CLASSPATH`:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14\lib and `JAVA_HOME`: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14

Comment: you should have it in PATH ending with bin folder like following

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin

Comment: yes, I have this