# how can I change java version(android studio)

Tags: java, flutter, macos, android-studio

```
$ java -version
java version "17.0.3.1" 2022-04-22 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```

However when I run Flutter:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle. │
│                                                                               │
│ To get Java 11, update to the latest version of Android Studio on             │
│ https://developer.android.com/studio/install.                                 │
│                                                                               │
│ To check the Java version used by Flutter, run `flutter doctor -v`.           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I can change gradle.properties like: `org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`.
It worked, just this project, ever time `new project` need change again. How can I fix it.

env:

1. Android Studio version: 3.5.2
2. macos

try:

1. fail
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqSsT.png)
2. fail
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqbOw.png)
3. cant find  `Gradle JVM`
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeHPH.png)

Comment: can this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur) help you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying every time you create a new project you get this error? Or every time you try to run the project?
Either way, it might be an IDE setting that is fixed in using JAVA 8 but your Gradle is configured for JAVA 11, thus causing the problem.
Your stack trace already tells you where to look at:

- changing the IDE settings.
- changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
- changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

So make sure all of these are using the same JAVA version.