# Unable to run flutter app on android emulator as java as Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I've tried to install newest version of java but it doesn't seem to work for android emulator (works fine with ios emulator as problem lies with `java` version). *Also there is no updates for java tab in system preferences*

- here is the error message :

```
Build file '/Users/aayush/Documents/MINOR PROJECT/inventory-management-app/spence/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] You need Java 11 or higher to build your app with this version of Gradle. │
│                                                                               │
│ To get Java 11, update to the latest version of Android Studio on             │
│ https://developer.android.com/studio/install.                                 │
│                                                                               │
│ To check the Java version used by Flutter, run `flutter doctor -v`.           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited
```

- here is the outputs of command `java --version`

```
java 18.0.2 2022-07-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+9-61)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+9-61, mixed mode, sharing)
```

- here is the output of command `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64, locale en)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at /Users/aayush/Documents/Flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (3 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/aayush/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/aayush/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

How can I change the java version to newer one from 1.8 as flutter keep using older one. *(in MacOS)*

Comment: The output shows that you Java 18 and Java 8 installed. Most likely Gradle uses Java 8 and thus fails. Check your environment variables like `JAVA_HOME` if one points to the Java 8 installation and check all of them to Java 18.

Comment: @Robert , I've already put `export JAVA_HOME=\`/usr/libexec/java_home\`` in `.bash_profile` but problem is still there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked from all answers of [Android Studio Error "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur)

> What worked for me was **UNINSTILLATION OF ANDROID STUDIO** :)

Everything worked. no more error from flutter.