# Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution Visual Studio Code Mac Issues

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code, gradle.properties

My flutter app was not working in Visual Studio Code today and I got this error:

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip'.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
You can try some of the following options:
  - changing the IDE settings.
  - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
  - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

I did some research and came across this [great thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur) and have been trying to get mine to work.

I downloaded the latest Java and updated it in Android Studio:

[image]

That fixed on error. I used to get the error twice, Now I onlg get this one:

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip'.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
You can try some of the following options:
  - changing the IDE settings.
  - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
  - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

I then decided to try updating `gradle.properties`

and I added the path to my new Java download like this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I got that path from running `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11` in a terminal

I then ran flutter clean and a pub get and I am still receiving the same error. No dice..

**Update:**

Ran `java --version` in terminal withing Visual Studio code and got this:

```
openjdk 11.0.16 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.16+8 (build 11.0.16+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.16+8 (build 11.0.16+8, mixed mode)
```

**Update2:**

So now this is super odd. I have narrowed this down to only affecting Visual Studio Code. Android Studio, runs my app fine...