# Flutter : Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle, java-11

I can't edit my jdk version Here:

[image]

And when I execute gradlew --version It says that I'm using Java 11:

[image]

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur

Comment: I fixed the problem by updating my Android Studio version.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to open your project structure settings ? Here is how:

1. Click on the gear icon in the top right corner
2. Select Project Structure

[image: project structure]

3. Click SDK Location
4. Click gradle settings
5. Then select your jdk version
   [image: Choose JDK version]

Comment: I wasn't having this SDK Location in the project structure, but I fixed the problem by upgrading my android studio. Thanks

Comment: Great, and as always, happy coding hhee

Answer (score 0):

issue happening on **windows 11** and **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1**
copy the content inside path "*program Files/java/jdk*" inside path "*program Files/Android/AndoridStudio/jre*"  fixing my problem after ***restarting*** the ***IDE***