Stuck in a cycle of incompatible gradle version in Android Studio
I see similar questions have been asked before, but they do not cover the full scope of issue I am facing.
I am a beginner and whenever I create a new android project, the default auto generated gradle wrapper version is set to 8.4
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

But the build fails because of the following error -
> Unsupported Gradle.  The project uses Gradle version which is
> incompatible with Android Studio 2023.2.
Possible solution:
 - Open Gradle wrapper settings, upgrade version to 3.0 or newer and reload the project

This is really odd behaviour since the IDE is the one deciding on which version to use. Now if I change the url to 8.2, it fails because of the following error -
Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.4. Current version is 8.2.
Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Change Gradle version in Gradle wrapper to 8.4 and re-import project
Open Gradle wrapper properties
Gradle Settings.

So this just puts me in a cycle of errors.
Some adhoc info-  My plugin version is 8.3.1 and it doesn't seem to be editable
Edit - Based on comments I tried running ./gradlew --version.
When I tried it with version 8.2, the command worked fine and showed version 8.2. When I tried the same with 8.4(the one I need right now)
with the following url
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip

I get an error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)


have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66980512/android-studio-error-android-gradle-plugin-requires-java-11-to-run-you-are-cur?rq=2

Have you tried using a different Android Studio version? Also, your first error indicates that you need to upgrade gradle wrapper.

@tomerpacific The url I updated was inside the graddle wrapper properties. I believe the URL is used to fetching the gradle wrapper.

@Yakubu I tried that and I have updated my edits accordingly. Appreciate the input but still need some help with the resolution

have you tried the steps below... also could you paste your build.gradle.kts
I want to see the version on id("com.android.application") version

Try to update your gradle
in your gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
update to
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

update your build.gradle.kts
id("com.android.application") version "8.3.0" apply false
id("com.android.library") version "8.3.0" apply false
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.23" apply false

in your settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {


    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {

  repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
  }
}

Then sync your project
you can read more here Android

So just updating to version 8.5 in the wrapper URL worked for me. Thanks

By the way, the latest available release as of the time of writing this comment is v8.7.
